# Issue with Ajax call if I move all the JS at the bottom of my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, performance

I am using BundleMinifyInlineJsCss NuGet package to move JavaScript to the end of the page. This will move all my JS before the closing of body tag. [Here](https://github.com/martijnlentink/InlineMinifier) you see the code for this package. I am facing an issue with Ajax Call because all JavaScript moved to the end of the page. Is there any option so I can add my script which is necessary for ajax call. Or Is there any option if I do not want to move that particular script to the end of the page.

Example: I am having one div in my view page like below:

```
<div id="xyz">
<div id="search-filters-placeholder" class="search-filters-block">
    <div class="filter-title">
        <span>Ergebnisfilterung</span>
    </div>   
    <div class="filter-item">
        <img class="filter-loading-img" src="MySource/loading_icon.gif" alt="" height="48" width="48" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ABC').ready(function () {
    $('#xyz').replaceWith($('#search-filters'));
    $('#search-filters').fadeIn();
});
```

Now for this div I am executing one script. But main problem is that Ajax response does not contain script tag. As ajax response does not contain body tag it only contain all the div tags only. 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to post a minimal example of what you're doing, and explain the problem in more detail than just "I am facing an issue".

Comment: What error are you getting? show us your code, etc.

Comment: Moving code to the end isn't usually a problem. Javascript problems usually happen when you have it at the beginning, because you try to access elements that haven't been loaded into the DOM yet.

Comment: Why does moving it to the end cause a problem?

Comment: After moving all JS at the end of the page in Ajax Response it doe not contain script part.

Comment: @StijnBernards - Error: B is undefined. As in ajax response it will not get any script tag.

Comment: @Barmar : After moving js, in ajax response it does not contain my script.

Comment: What script? Please show the AJAX call.

Comment: @Barmar : Problem is not with Ajax call. If I am putting my script after my div  then everything works fine.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "for this div I am executing one script". What script are you executing, how are you executing it? The question is impossible to answer if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Barmar :I have updated my JS.

Comment: You wrote "I am facing an issue with Ajax call". I don't see an Ajax call.